# NullPointerException: android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)'

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I am trying to show data in `drawerLayout` by using `ListView` and `customAdapter` class but I am facing an error and I am confused to find the solution, why is it showing me `NullPointerException`?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nabia.myapplication/com.example.nabia.myapplication.Activities.FindNearbyMosque}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
           at com.example.nabia.myapplication.Activities.FindNearbyMosque.onCreate(FindNearbyMosque.java:94)
           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

My `ListView` code is given below.

```
public class FindNearbyMosque extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<ItemSlideMenu> itemSlideMenus;
    private SlidingMenuAdapter slidingMenuAdapter;
    private ListView listviewsliding;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Init component
        listviewsliding = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        itemSlideMenus = new ArrayList<>();
        //Add itmes for sliding list
        itemSlideMenus.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.time, "Masjid Timing"));
        itemSlideMenus.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.mosque, "My Mosque"));
        itemSlideMenus.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.settings, "Setting"));
        slidingMenuAdapter = new SlidingMenuAdapter(this, itemSlideMenus);
        listviewsliding.setAdapter(slidingMenuAdapter);

        //Display icon to open/ close sliding list
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //Set title
        setTitle(itemSlideMenus.get(0).getTitle());
        //Item selected
        listviewsliding.setItemChecked(0, true);
        //Close menu
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listviewsliding);

        //Display fragment 1 when start
        replaceFragment(0);

        //Handle on item click
        listviewsliding.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Set title
                setTitle(itemSlideMenus.get(position).getTitle());
                //Item selected
                listviewsliding.setItemChecked(position, true);
                //Replce Fragment
                replaceFragment(position);
                //close menu
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listviewsliding);
            }
        });

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    //Create method replace fragment

    private void replaceFragment (int pos){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (pos){
            case 0:
                fragment = new MasjidTiming();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new MyMosque();
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment = new Settings();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new MasjidTiming();
                break;
        }
        if (null!=fragment)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_consent, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter class is:

```
public class SlidingMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<ItemSlideMenu> Istitem;

    public SlidingMenuAdapter(FindNearbyMosque context, List<ItemSlideMenu> istitem) {
        this.context = context;
        Istitem = istitem;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return Istitem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Istitem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v=View.inflate(context, R.layout.itme_sliding_menu,null);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_img);
        TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_title);

        ItemSlideMenu itemSlideMenu=Istitem.get(position);
        img.setImageResource(itemSlideMenu.getImgid());
        tv.setText(itemSlideMenu.getTitle());
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I have reviewed it but I could not find my solution from it.

Comment: It says your listviewsliding is null. Please check your XML once to match the ID.

Comment: **Every** NPE has the **same origin**: An object has been used before it has been instanced. And **Every** NPE has the **same solution**: Find that object and instance it before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't called setContentView in your activity which makes it impossible to find your ListView.

Comment: Your answer is helpful but it is not fixing main problem. My problem is still same.

Comment: It's solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter Class, change this line

```
View v=View.inflate(context, R.layout.itme_sliding_menu,null);
```

with

```
if(convertView == null){
    convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.itme_sliding_menu,null);
}
```

And replace `return v;` with `return convertView;`

Comment: It is not fixing my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem by adding `setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);` line in `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to try cleaning your project. This has solved my problem. I suppose android studio generated bad list of ids which lead to runtime error.